# flutter circle checkbox with text inside

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I create round checkboxes with text inside ?
I want it like on the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a button that on pressed toggles a bool and based on if bool is true or false you can make the border be transparent or not.
This may not be the best solution but it should work

```
class CustomCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<CustomCheckbox> createState() => _CustomCheckboxState();
}

class _CustomCheckboxState extends State<CustomCheckbox> {
  bool isChecked = false;
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() => isChecked = !isChecked);
      },
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: Text(
        'AS',
        style: TextStyle(
           color: isChecked ? Colors.white : Colors.grey,
           fontSize: 20
        )
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
      shape: CircleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(
           color: isChecked ? Colors.yellowAccent : Colors.transparent 
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

try using ClipOval in a row children

```
   ClipOval(
   child:
   Container(
   color: yourColor
   height: 10.0,
   width: 10.0,
   ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Checkbox extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value;
  final bool check;
  const Checkbox({
   Key? key, required this.value, required this.check,
 }) : super(key: key);

  @override
 State<Checkbox> createState() => _CheckboxState();
  }

 class _CheckboxState extends State<Checkbox> {
 late bool check;
  @override
  void initState() {
  check = widget.check;
    super.initState();
}
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return InkWell(
    onTap: (){
    setState(()=>check = !check);
   },
    child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      border: Border.all(color: check ? Colors.yellow : Colors.transparent, 
      width: 2),
        ),
         child: Text(widget.value, style: TextStyle(color: check ? Colors.white 
         : Colors.grey)),
       ),
      );
  }
 }
```